# How to upload iOS image from gallery via multipart/form data withSwift 5

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, httprequest, multipartform-data

I have picked UIImage object from an iOS gallery and want to send by HTTP on API using multipart/form-data. It's working with Postman and Node.js but I having a problem with same request by Swift.

Initialization part

```
import Foundation

var image: UIImage?
let postURL = "http://......"

extension NSMutableData {
  func appendString(_ string: String) {
    if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
      self.append(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Request preparation

```
let imageJpeg: Data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)

func convertFiledData(fieldName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String, fileData: Data, fileString: String, using boundary: String) -> Data {
    let data = NSMutableData()
                  
    data.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    data.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; file=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
    data.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
    data.append(fileData)
    data.appendString("\r\n")
    data.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    
    return data as Data
}

let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: postURL)!, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
let mimeType = "image/jpeg"

let httpBody = convertFiledData(fieldName: "file",
                                fileName: "xray1.jpg",
                                mimeType: mimeType,
                                fileData: imageJpeg,
                                fileString: imageString,
                                using: boundary)
                
request.httpBody = httpBody as Data
```

Request part

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, err) in
    do {
       if let data = data {
       let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PostModel.self, from: data )
           } else {
              print("No data")
           }
           } catch (let error) {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
             }
 }.resume()
```

Request is working well. Body assembling as need. I have 422 HTTP error code.

There is res object shows

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600001e9e0a0> { URL: http://.... } { Status Code: 422, Headers {
    "Content-Length" =     (
        110
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 20 Dec 2021 04:30:59 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        uvicorn
    );
} })
```

This is data from URLSession Data sent by FastAPi server

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}
```

It's looks like a problem with file data format. Probably in .jsonData() part. I tried some other transformations but without any result.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this issue, but I think the problem may reside in this line:

`data.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; file=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")`

the last part should be `filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n`.

I was getting a similar error response, but in my case the problem was I didn't pass the extension name `.jpg` after the file name, some servers don't recognize your image file without an extension name.

Leaving this answer here as a reference in case people run into a similar problem.